# Cant pass barcodes scan from scan stream into a list

Tags: flutter, dart

im trying to do a scan stream for the barcode scanner that when i open the scan stream every barcode that the scanner detect will be add to the data list

scanning one item in barcode scan is working but scan stream isnt working properly

**this is the function od scanning:**

```
startBarcodeScanStream() async {
    FlutterBarcodeScanner.getBarcodeStreamReceiver("#ff6666", "Cancel", true)
        .listen((barcode) => addBarcodeTolist(barcode.toString()));
  }    
  void addBarcodeTolist(barcode) {
    data.add(barcode);
  }
```

**and here I'm trying to access it:**

```
RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
            await startBarcodeScanStream();
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                print("this is data number :${data[i]}");
        },
```

Comment: please be more specific, what happens that is unexpected?

Comment: nothing happendeds, thats the problem when i scan barcode from the barcode stream the listen method sould detect a barcode and them add it the data list,